# How do you pass parameters to Hibernate's subselect tag?

Tags: java, hibernate, parameters, readonly, subquery

The example at the end of [hibernate section 5.1.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) does not show an example on passing parameters.

> There is no difference between a view
>   and a base table for a Hibernate
>   mapping. This is transparent at the
>   database level, although some DBMS do
>   not support views properly, especially
>   with updates. Sometimes you want to
>   use a view, but you cannot create one
>   in the database (i.e. with a legacy
>   schema). In this case, you can map an
>   immutable and read-only entity to a
>   given SQL subselect expression:

```
<class name="Summary">
    <subselect>
        select item.name, max(bid.amount), count(*)
        from item
        join bid on bid.item_id = item.id
        group by item.name
    </subselect>
    <synchronize table="item"/>
    <synchronize table="bid"/>
    <id name="name"/>
    ...
</class>
```

Is it possible? And if so, how?

Thanks,
Franz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible, because the mapping file is like a static description.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate 3 you can use formulas to map this types of readonly calculated fields. Example:

```
@Formula("(SELECT b.BANK_NAME FROM " +
        " BANK_INFORMATION b, BILLING_AGENT_BANK ba " +
        " WHERE ba.CNPJ = COMPANY_CNPJ " +
        " AND b.BANK_ID = ba.BANK_ID)")
public String getBankName() {
    return bankName;
}
```

This example is with a Annotated property, but you can do the same in the mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

In NHibernate:

```
<class name="Blog" mutable="false"> 
<subselect> 
  SELECT Blog.Id, Blog.Author, Blog.Title, Comment.Comment 
  FROM Blog INNER JOIN Comment ON Blog.Id = Comment.Blog_id 
  WHERE Comment.LanguageId = :blogcomment.languageId 
</subselect> 
<id name="Id"> 
  <generator class="assigned" /> 
</id> 
<property name="Author" /> 
<property name="Title" /> 
<property name="Comment" />
```